# Unload matrix and free memory

Tags: matlab

I can load a matrix from text file:

```
load mydata.txt
```

The problem is my matrix file is about 250Mb and after several such loads I have no memory to work with next files.

How could unload it and free resources for further use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [clear](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/clear.html), or [clearvars](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/clearvars.html). By default, MATLAB will create a variable called mydata as a result of your statement, so

```
clear mydata
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the variables in your workspace that contain the large data sets and in your script or from the console type

```
clear whateverVariableName
```

To clear all memory use

```
clear all
```

You can even right-click individual variables in he workspace editor and delete them using the IDE if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do `clear mydata` and then issue `pack` . The first command says to Matlab that the reference to the memory held for mydata is not needed anymore. The second command instruct the Matlab to free unused memory. If you don't issue `pack`, then memory will be deallocated when the Matlab memory manager decides to.